# jquery selector looping vs using function each

Tags: jquery

1. Do these two snippets of code do identical things?  If yes, when should one be used over the other? (besides when you need to do something involving `i` or `value`)

   ```
   $("foo").each(function(i,value) {
       $(this).empty();
   });
   ```

   vs.

   ```
   $("foo").empty();
   ```
2. In general can it be assumed that `$("foo").someMethod()` means "run `somemethod()` on *each* element that matches the selector, except if the name of the method is `each`? (ie each is a special case)

Comment: If you don't need the index of the item that you are emptying, there is no need to use an `each()` command. Go with the shorter syntax.

Comment: @Lix: it also runs faster: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-looping-vs-using-function-each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to stock jQuery functions, yes, the two snippets of code are identical.

You should use the `each()` function either when you want to work with the index, or to prevent long function chaining.

Your understanding of `$('foo').someMethod()` is true of  jQuery methods. But be warned, some plugins may handle the selector in a different manner, or only affect the first matched element for example.

Comment: could you elaborate on how a plugin might 'dirty' the jquery selector in such a fashion? (if you were referring to $(' ' ))

Comment: It doesn't 'dirty' the selector as such, but the plugin might only be capable of handling the first matched element, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, most jQuery function are designed like this.

Look at the code example:

```
$.fn.someMethod = function() {
   return this.each(function() {
      do_something(this); 
   });
};
```

So even you could use `.each` again, you should just use:

`$(selector).someMethod();`

not

```
$(selector).each(function() {
  $(this).someMethod();
});
```

Comment: my current jquery noob-ness doesnt understand the significance. can you pls explain the `$.fn.someMethod` part.

Comment: @wal This means put the method on the prototype of jQuery.You could check some articles of how to make a jQuery plugin.